# javafx sometimes cannot detect multiple keys input

Tags: java, javafx

I am working on a 2D tank game. When I press two arrow keys simultaneously(such as up and right), the tank should go forward and rotate right at the same time. However, when I release one key (For example, I press up and right at the same time then release right but keep pressing up. Theoretically the tank should stop rotating and keep going forward), the tank stops directly. Why?
My code:

```
    getScene().setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
            onKeyPressed(event);
            move();
        }
    });
    getScene().setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>(){
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent event){
            onKeyReleased(event);
        }
    });

public void onKeyPressed(KeyEvent event){
    switch (event.getCode()){
        case LEFT:
            isPressLeft=true;
            break;
        case RIGHT:
            isPressRight=true;
            break;
        case UP:
            isPressUp=true;
            break;
        case DOWN:
            isPressDown=true;
            break;
    }
}

public void move(){
    if (isPressUp){
        panzer.moveUp();
        if (isPressRight){
            panzer.rotateRight();
        }else if (isPressLeft){
            panzer.rotateLeft();
        }
    }else if (isPressDown){
        panzer.moveDown();
        if (isPressRight){
            panzer.rotateRight();
        }else if (isPressLeft){
            panzer.rotateLeft();
        }
    }else if (isPressLeft){
        panzer.rotateLeft();
    }else if (isPressRight){
        panzer.rotateRight();
    }
}

public void onKeyReleased(KeyEvent event){
    switch (event.getCode()){
        case LEFT:
            isPressLeft=false;
            break;
        case RIGHT:
            isPressRight=false;
            break;
        case UP:
            isPressUp=false;
            break;
        case DOWN:
            isPressDown=false;
            break;
    }
}
```

I have tried the single stepping, when I release the right key, only isPressRight is changed to false. The isPressUp is still true. I think the problem may be in move().

Answer (score 1):

That is a sticky keys issue. I've had that before.

Do this.

```
// In move method
if (!isPressLeft && !isPressRight){} // Set the rotating speed of the player to 0 or whatever you do
if (!isPressUp && !isPressDown){} // Set velocity of the player to 0 or whatever you do.
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer solves "half" of my problem. After adding your code, the tank has about 50% of chance to keep going or rotating in correct direction after releasing one key. Sometimes the tank still stop. It is weird. Please could you explain "sticky keys issue" specifically?

Comment: After more test, I find out what time the bug happens: when I press up firstly then press right, the tank starts going forward and rotating right. If I release up and keep pressing right, the tank stops going forward and only rotates right normally, but if I release right firstly, the tank just stops moving and rotating. Similarly, if I hold right firstly and release up firstly, the tank also stops.

Comment: I created this to learn what you are working on. Go check out the diver class. https://github.com/sedj601/DiverFx